# Finding the design pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I've done a couple of integrations that are similar. In one, I was taking product data from one system's database, formatting the product data to work with another systems database and then import those products into that system. In another, I was taking users from one systems database, formatting them, and then importing into another system. There seems like there would be a design pattern for this, what is it if there is one?

Comment: Not sure if I would call this a design pattern.  "Clean, Conform, Deliver" CCD or "Extract, Transform, Load" ETL are terms I would use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two design pattern for
this senerio.

**Adapter Pattern:**
If you want to have one way communiction

Reason: You have two system System1DB  System2DB and
There is only one way communication

```
          Your Adapter
Sytem1DB --------------> System2DB
```

**Mediator Pattern:**
If you want to have two way
communication on homogenius system

```
          Your Mediator
Sytem1DB <----------------> System2DB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Factory pattern in building Product list, and user list.

Answer (score 0):

To me, you are talking about data transformations from one DB to another.

The Driver design pattern is always used to abstract the program from a database implementation.

Then, you have your "transformation pipe": an orientend graph of transformations. It is mostly something you could do with generic programming. Each transformation waits for an input data of type IN_T and transforms it into a possibly different output of type OUT_T.

So here could come the Visitor design pattern to visit your graph to execute the transformation; the Decorator design pattern to change properties of the graph nodes; the State design pattern to express the state of a transformation; the Listener design pattern to give an update of the transformation progress; etc.